# What does VARBINARY(MAX) mean?

Tags: sql, mariadb, varbinary, varbinarymax

I'm trying to port a MSSQL database over to MariaDB and I've encountered a table creation using varbinary(max):

```
    `definition` VARBINARY(max) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

What would this actually do and is there an equivalent type definition in MariaDB that I could use?

Comment: [The BINARY and VARBINARY Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)

Comment: The first hit on google with the search terms `varbinary(max)` goes to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). From there: *Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. **max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, `VARBINARY(max)` in MSSQL refers to:

> Variable-length binary data.
>
> max indicates that the maximum storage size is `2^31-1` bytes.

From what I found in MariaDB's documentation, the only way of getting a similar storage size in MariaDB is to use the `LONGBLOB` data type:

> LONGBLOB
>
> A BLOB column with a maximum length of `4,294,967,295` bytes or `4GB` (`2^32 - 1`).

Useful links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx

http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/datatypes.php

Comment: Well.. i found the VarBinary type in MySql workbench tool (When i create table) too. MySql is very similar with maria db so, i guess that using long blob is not the only way in maria(or mysql).

Comment: When dealing with strings, what encoding type does MSSQL use for `varbinar(max)`?  Is it `utf16le`?  I'm running SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, VARBINARY is variable length binary data, the MAX scale value means it will store up to the maximum 2^31-1 bytes.

I think the closest equivalent MariaDB data type will be LONGBLOB, which can store up to 2^32-1 bytes.